# Jenkins not filtering global passwords for Maven build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Using the EnvInject plugin, I have added a password to the Global Passwords list, like so:

[image]

Within the job, I enable global passwords, like so:

[image]

I was under the assumption that using the name as an environment variable within the Maven build goal would work just fine, like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, I see this in the build output:

```
.../my-project/pom.xml clean install -Dwhatever.password=${qa.password}
```

What am I missing?  I've been toying around with config for a while, but this seems like it should work for what I'm trying to accomplish.

*For the sake of the question, the reasoning for utilizing a password as a maven option is out of the context of this question.*

Comment: Did you try `-Dwhatever.password=$qa.password` or `-Dwhatever.password=%qa.password%`

Comment: I did, it just spits that right back out in the console log :-/

Comment: Did you try putting it in MAVEN_OPTS field? The MAVEN_OPTS field is usually hidden inside the 'Advanced' section

Comment: Has this ever been solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think a dot is not a valid character in an environmental variable. Maybe try renaming the variable to 'qa_password' or something?